# Reordering MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql, database

I have probably a very simple question. 
I have a MySQL database called "alldata", which contains various variables. The first column called LogDateTime contains date and time. Now the thing is that I want the db to be sorted from the oldest to the newest - in other words by column 1.

I know how to do a MySQL query using ORDER BY Logdatetime etc. But what I would like to do is to reorder tha data in the actual database and save it ordered. Right now there are some dates a bit messed up. Then I would not have to use the ORDER BY statement in all my queries because the database would already be sorted.

Could anyone please just give me the SQL command I should use to reorder the entire database?

Comment: Relational databases are not ordered.

Comment: You misunderstand, how your data appears on the screen is arbitrary,the only way to guarantee a order is with ORDER BY.

Comment: You miss the biggest advantage of relational databases: You don't have to care how it's stored internally if you don't want to

Comment: If you're using InnoDB, the database is stored internally sorted by the primary key, you can't change that.

Comment: OK, well the thing is, the data is added to the db automatically every 5 min by a script. The newest data is therefore always at the end. Unfortunately at the beginning when I was uploading the first batch of data, there were some unordered values. 
So my question then is, if I make a query without any ORDER BY, what determines the order in which the values are passed to the result?

Comment: Nothing determines the order, it could be totally random.

Comment: I found some suggestions on the web now, what then happens it I try this:

ALTER TABLE  `alldata` ORDER BY  `LogDateTime`

Comment: If you're worried about the inefficiency of using ORDER BY in your queries, make sure you have an index on `LogDateTime`. It will use that to optimize ordering the result.

Comment: Didn't you get that from the **Related** questions in the sidebar?

Comment: I have that. Well thanx for your help anyway, just wondering that everytime I try it without, it sends the values in the order I see them in phpBB - mostly ordered by LogDateTime except the few unordered ones.

Comment: No, I found that in the phpBB documentation.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot setup a relational database table to return results ordered by a specific column of your choosing.  You need to use `ORDER BY`.  You could work around this by using views.

The view definition would include an `ORDER BY`.  You could select from the view and it would show results in your desired order.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE VIEW `mytable_view` AS SELECT * FROM `my_table` ORDER BY `my_date_column`
```

Then you can select the data:

```
SELECT * FROM `mytable_view`
```

Results are shown in desired order.